# Is it true that:$X>Y$ implies $\mathbb Eg(X)>\mathbb Eg(Y)$ for $g$ is strictly increasing function

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, random-variables, expectation

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two random variable. Let X>Y stochastically and $g$ is an strictly increasing function. Is it true that E(g(X))>E(g(Y)) strictly and how to prove it?

By $X>Y$ stochastically I mean $P(X>t)\geq P(Y>t)$ for all $t$ and $P(X>t)> P(Y>t)$ for some $t$. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "$X>Y$ stochastically"?

Comment: @drhab. Thanks for attention. I define the point and edited the question.

Comment: I suspect that you meant $>$ instead of $\geq$ if it comes to "some $t$". And why $t>0$?

Comment: @drhab These are mistakes. I corrected the two points. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It might be useful to start more humble. Does it hold that $\mathbb E(X)<\mathbb E(Y)$ in this situation (provided that the expectations exist)? This (even more humble) under the restriction that $X$ and $Y$ are nonnegative? Maybe it is possible to prove this on base of $\mathbb E(X)=\int_0^{\infty} P(X>t)dt$. To make it more general: if $X>Y$ stochastically does that imply that $g(X)>g(Y)$ stochastically?

Comment: In my former comment I mean $\mathbb EX>\mathbb EY$.

Comment: The key, point, is it not, is that there exists some $t^*$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $P(X>t) > P(Y>t)$ on some interval $(t^*-\epsilon, t^*]$ (some $\epsilon > 0$). This is true by the assumptions and the left continuity of distribution functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to understand $X>Y$ stochastically, is that it is equivalent to there existing a *coupling* between $X$ and $Y$, say random variable $u$, such that $X(u)>Y(u)$ for all values of $u$ (except on a set of probability zero) and $X(u)$ is identical to $X$ in distribution (same for $Y$).

If $g$ is strictly increasing, then $E_X(g(X))=E_u(g(X(u)))>E_u(g(Y(u)))=E_Y(g(Y))$.

This is not very precise, but it maybe could be fleshed out to be more rigorous.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: Glad to help out when I can. Coupling is a very useful concept. I learned about it studying interacting particle systems from T Ligget's book.